# laravel separate Login Errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication

when we use laravel after enter email and password and when our email or password pr both of them are wrong, the laravel tell us just one message for all   probably situations , i just want to separate the errors , e.g your password is wrong or your email not found or we cannot find this user etc.
i just customize the auth.php file in lang folder and set this :

```
'failed' => 'Login Failed!!',
```

i want to add more condition for my login errors

please help me to do this task

thanks for your helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to do it separately in terms of protecting the privacy of the users, because the general error message doesn't categorically inform the potentially malicious person or bot that "You found the right email, now all you have to guess is the password".

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is adding `exists:users` validation to the `validateLogin` method of `AuthenticatesUsers` trait by overriding it on Login Controller:

```
// app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string|exists:users',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

It will check if the entered username (by default email) exists on users table or not.

Comment: thanks for your help , for other errors , do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It not a good idea to separate both as it will let others know which section or input they entered wrong.

You can add on the message of login failed!!! but dont let the user know which part they entered wrongly.